# Is it true that for iPad and iPhone, using CADisplayLink must be for 60fps?

Tags: ios, cadisplaylink

In other words, can we choose to invoke the handler at 20 times per second, or at 45 times per second, or must it be 60 times per second?

I guess one way to simulate it will be to use the timestamp given to the handler to determine if it is "time for action yet" -- if not, simply return without doing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`frameInterval`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031-CH1-SW4) property to invoke the handler every `60/n` frames, where `n` is a positive integer.

You can't invoke the handler `45` times per second, but the following values are possible: `60`, `30`, `20`, `15`, `12`, ...